# Sending email such that "from" is a name or text rather than real email address

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am sending email using Java Mail API. When the email is received in the inbox its shows the email address used to send the email. I want to hide the from email address and show some text. I think its possible because when I get an email from facebook, in the inbox it says "Facebook - Email subject" rather than "xyz@facebook.com - Email Subject".

I want to do the same using Java Mail API.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the Constructor

```
InternetAddress(String address, String personal)
```

when building your sender address. In your example this would be

```
sender = new InternetAddress("xyz@facebook.com","Facebook");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside the try block:

```java
// Set From: 
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("displayname<"+from+">"));
```